# Stopping eclipse LogCat to receive logs

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, logcat, android-logcat

I am working on Unity based Android application which sends 5000 logs in a second. 
To Debug, I need to remove USB cable to check the logs otherwise news logs will be overridden by old ones.

I know I can increase the no of lines for logging, but what I want is stop getting logs so that I can read the logs logged and can work on them.

I know I can stop adb server with `adb kill-server` command, but the problem is after running that command in Command prompt, if I browse LogCat logs the tab is getting switched to Console tab which is showing Connection attempts.

```
[2015-05-06 14:30:26 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2015-05-06 14:30:28 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2015-05-06 14:30:30 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2015-05-06 14:30:32 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
```

I want to stop getting logs without removing USB cable so that I can browse the logs to debug.

Comment: try using tag filter to read your app specific logs

Comment: Tags can't fully help by the time. Even with this tag, I will miss some important logs because the logs will be overridded after 1,00,000 lines of logs

Answer (score 0):

You could write those logs to file using a wrapper function around `Log.i()` and it's cousins.

Answer (score 0):

Add this [Logger](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fj7k2fx7yuhmd6/Logger.java?dl=0) class to your project, and use the `TYPE_DISC` to save all the logs to device's storage.. from there you can check the logs

Also, you will get option to show logs on terminal or post to server.